# Аргументы класса из файла

Tags: python

Ребят, понимаю что вопрос тупой, но как подтянуть аргументы для класса из файла?
Вот мы считываем нужную строчку из файла, закидываем в ее список.

```
class_list =[]
with open('notebook.txt', 'r') as class_append:
    for argument in class_append:
        class_list.append(argument)
```

Потом закидываем это аргументами класса

```
asus = Notebook(class_list)
```

А класс это принимает как один аргумент, split не помогает, на других языках такия статьи есть, python не нашел.

Comment: `Notebook(*class_list)`,  почитайте про *args*, *kwargs* в питоне

Comment: Увы, это тоже не помогло, все та же недостача аргументов.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A:
def __init__(self, a,b,*args):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
def print_args(self):
    print(self.a, self.b)

d=[i for i in range(5)]
A(*d).print_args() # результат 0, 1
```

`